# What's the if statement to print this matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm passing a matrix as input( c++) and I want to print out the numbers from the outside of the matrix, the "hollow square element" of it. I know how to do that, and it's this if statement: `if(i==0 || i==n || j==0 ||  j==n)`. I want to print the next frame of the matrix, because with this if statement it prints  the outside frame of the matrix. I want to print all of the next frames.

I already did the outside of the matrix using `if(i==0 || i==n || j==0 || j==n)` but as I said it prints the first frame of the matrix and I want to print the next frames.

For example, given the matrix

```
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
5 6 7 8
8 7 6 5
```

It should print:

```
3 2
6 7
```

So it is the "second" frame,which is the inside of the matrix. The first frame would have been:

```
1 2 3 4
4     1
5     8
8 7 6 5
```

So,  how do I print the next frames?

Comment: replace `0` with `1` and `n` with `n-1`

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried this already. For that, instead of 3,2,6,7 it only shows 3 and 7

Comment: Ah right, you'd have to add `i>0` etc to each part of the if statement to exclude the outer rings. But I'm sure there's a better way to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your matrix has the size of `n+1` x `n+1`, I think the following condition will work for any size square matrix:

```
if(((i==1 || i==n-1) && (j>0 && j<n)) || ((i>0 && i<n) && (j==1 || j==n-1)))
```

In general, k-th frame can be printed by the following condition:

```
if(((i==k || i==n-k) && (j>=k && j<=n-k)) || ((i>=k && i<=n-k) && (j==k || j==n-k)))
```

For k=0, this condition reduces to the first one `if(i==0||i==n||j==0||j==n)`.

Answer (score 1):

in order to print is everything BUT the outer frame, simply do a negation of you current boolean :

`if(!(i==0 || i==n || j==0 || j==n))`

By De Morgan's law this translates to :

`if( i != 0 && i != n && j != 0  && j != n)`

if you want to iterate over the different frames of your matrix a for loop is needed:

`for(int depth = 0; depth < mat.row()/2 < depth++)
   if(((i==depth || i==n-depth) && (j>depth-1 && j<n - depth )) || ((i>depth -1 && i<n - depth ) && (j==depth || j==n-depth)))`

Comment: I don't what EVERYTHING but the outer frame, I want the NEXT frame, and then the NEXT FRAME, not everything

Comment: @DmytroDadyka please tell me how I didn't? 

"I want to print the next frame of the matrix"

Comment: And how do I iterate over these frames?... That's what I'm asking @Luisjomen2a

Comment: @PaulP1 you'll need to be use the number of rows (or columns since you are working with squared matrices). Keep in mind that this only work for matrices with a pair number of lines :

`for(int depth = 0; depth < mat.row()/2 < depth++)
   if(((i==depth || i==n-depth) && (j>depth-1 && j<n - depth )) || ((i>depth -1 && i<n - depth ) && (j==depth || j==n-depth))) 
`

A bit messy but something like that : I'll add it to my answer

Comment: It's okay if I know how to print the k-th frame, I'll figure it out how to print all of the frames in a sequence later. @DmytroDadyka